# SignalR: Catching server exceptions on Javascript client with properties intact

Tags: javascript, exception, signalr, signalr-hub

I got in a simple sample on the server-side hub this method:

```
    public int CanThrowException(int input)
    {
        if (0==input)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input", "was zero");
        return -input;
    }
```

On the client this:

```
$.connection.testHub.server.canThrowException(0).fail(function (x)
{
    console.log(x);
});
```

Now what I get when I check `x` is a string containing parameter name and my message.

What I'm looking for is a way to get an actual Javascript object mirroring the properties of the server-side exception. So, in the given case, it should have the properties `message`, `actualValue` and `ParamName`.

Why do I want this? Because I want to write server-side code which usually will return objects, but in certain cases would throw an exception which would contain detailed information about the error which in turn makes absolute sense in my scenario to show to the user (actually, it not just makes sense, it is necessary).

Now of course, I could call some `client.caller.OnErrorThisAndThat()` method upon catching the exception server-side. However, that would make my JavaScript code more complicated, because I'd have to keep state which server-side method I called last, hook into that callback and make a connection between these two.

So is there a way to get typed exception proxies on the JavaScript client?
And if not, any ideas how to achieve what I want without them, except the mentioned event-sorta-mess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a try catch statement around the hub methods that you could be throwing errors at.

Calling method on client when server throws:

```
public int CanThrowException(int input)
{
    try
    {
        if (0==input) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input", "was zero");
        }
        return -input;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Clients.Caller.ErrorOnServer(e);
    }
}
```

Returning error object:

```
public object CanThrowException(int input)
{
    try
    {
        if (0==input) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input", "was zero");
        }
        return -input;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return e;
    }
}
```

Both of these approaches will get you your error object on the client with its corresponding properties.  However, I would recommend against using this method if this is a customer facing application.  It's never good to expose exceptions to clients if it can be prevented.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In my case, those exceptions contains validation problems - so I want to use them on the client to mark those fields which violated validation rules with the information from the exception.

Comment: Does your answer imply (seeing that you're working at MS and seem to be answering a whole lot of SignalR questions ;) that there is no way to change signalR's default behavior to send an exception object over the wire rather than the concatenated string representations of some properties?

Comment: SignalR uses JSON.Net to serialize objects into JSON (this is what the client receives).  You could potentially replace the IJsonSerializer and special case Exceptions to do whatever you please.